# Outputting to a text file

Tags: python, text

How to print the following code to a .txt file

```
y = '10.1.1.' # /24 network, 
for x in range(255):
    x += 1
    print y + str(x) # not happy that it's in string, but how to print it into a.txt
```

There's copy paste, but would rather try something more interesting.

Comment: You do realize that your x=1 does nothing?

Comment: yes, just in haste to ask a first question, although a bad one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
f = open('myfile.txt', 'w')
for x in range(255):
    ip = "10.1.1.%s\n" % str(x)
    f.write(ip)
f.close()
```

Comment: This won't give the result required: write() does not add newlines, so you end up with a single line of output.

Comment: @mhawke: There's a newline character in ip, though.

Comment: @Fred: yes, you're right. sorry about that. Anyway, there *is* a problem with the range(255) being zero-based.

Answer (score 3):

scriptname.py >> output.txt

Comment: I think this is the more flexible solution.

Answer (score 1):

What is the `x += 1` for? It seems to be a workaround for `range(255)` being 0 based - which gives the sequence 0,1,2...254.

`range(1,256)` will better give you what you want.

An alternative to other answers:

```
NETWORK = '10.1.1'
f = open('outfile.txt', 'w')
try:
    for machine in range(1,256):
        print >> f, "%s.%s" % (NETWORK, machine)
finally:
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, you can use the print function's keyword argument
called file. "a" means "append."

```
f = open("network.txt", "a")
for i in range(1, 256):
    print("10.1.1." + str(i), file=f)
f.close()
```